# How can I call a function everytime onChange on select is triggered on a userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

So I have a userscript that parses the page and creates a select box and fills it with options.

Now I want to call a script whenever the user changes the selected index on the select box. Unfortunately it looks like the userscript only runs only once and won't be able to read future changes on the select.

I have tried:

1)

```
$('#selectBox').on('change', function() 
{...}
```

(Only run once?)

2) Injecting the function "function_to_call" via insertBefore with `<script>` tag and formatting my select line to this:

```
<select onChange="function_to_call.call(this,event)">...</select>
```

and it doesn't work, saying function_to_call is undefined

3) This function: https://gist.github.com/nylen/6234717 to inject my own function again but everything passed on the parameter is undefined.

Is it even possible for a userscript to listen on events continuously or is it only really a one time execution?

Comment: do you have a function named "function_to_call"?

Comment: it will be better if you create a fiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#selectBox').on('change', function() 
{...})
```

, the reason why this runs only once is because the event listeners attached to a dom element will gone once it is editted (by insertBefore changing innerHTML etc)

So use

```
$(document).on('change','#selectBox',function() 
{...})
```

This will work